# I get many surfaces when i Unwarp my mesh,(Only two selected)

Tags: modeling

i'm getting stacked with this issue please help ! it's the first time i use blender i've been modeling for the first time without noticing that i have deferent color faces on my mesh without applying any material or colors !

the mesh looks unified but whene i apply unwarping i get splited surfaces and when i use ambient oclusion it apply only ont this splited face,it's realy strange please help !! here a link to my model for anyone who want to check it !

http://www.mediafire.com/download/oo4iubpe5v7n856/Body06%282%29.rar

[image]

Comment: your normals are mostly backwards. Press the recalculate normals button to fix it.

Comment: Oh man thank i've wasted a lot a time tryin' to find a solution to this problem !  Thank you very much !!!